# iPhone emoji UTF-8 code convert to emoji jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, utf-8

I have a website which chat is synchronized with IOS and Android Apps. When a person sends a message from iPhone and inserts an IOS default emoji, it brings me the UTF8 encoded string like this - `\ud83d\ude0d`.

The point is messages are building and appending to the list with the `jQuery` function (runtime) ; 
In that case the js do not recognize the code and do not convert it to the emoji.

```
function handleMessage(message){
    var messageEl = '<li>';
    messageEl +='<p id="emoji_cont_3479">'+message.message+'</p>';
    messageEl += '</li>';
    jQuery(messageListContent).append(messageEl);
}

element.click(function(){
    var message = data_coming_from_server_with_ajax;
    handleMessage(message);
});
```

But when I manually run this code, it is converting the code to emoji after the  element has been created.

```
jQuery('#emoji_cont_'+message.mess_id).html('\ud83d\ude0d');
```

But when I change the value with dynamic message, it is still returning the 
utf-8 code.

```
jQuery('#emoji_cont_'+message.mess_id).html(msg);
```

What can I do in this case.